#  How to play a media file when receive a new message?

Tags: android, notifications, message

I want to create an Android application to play a recorded sound clip when receives a message from a specific sender, so I put this code in my smsReceiver(Broadcastreceiver)

`NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)`       `context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

```
     Notification notification = new Notification();        
     notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.newgps/raw/calmpiano");

 nm.notify(0, notification);
```

But it play a part of a sound. What can I do for to solve it.

Comment: this can be a deviçe's own setting

Comment: yup,, I think so,, But I solved it using `MediaPlayer` and a thread. Thanks for u'r comment..!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append `\raw` to the resource URI. At runtime, everything is compiled into a single directory with IDs, meaning calling `R.raw.*` refers to raw resources, even though all the resources are effectively in the same directory.

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.calmpiano);
```

And you can also specify some extra settings using `notification.default`, but **do not use `DEFAULT_SOUND`**. It will override the custom sound if the default sound is defined.